# Migrating asp.net from 32 bit to 64 bit webform application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an Asp webform application build in 3.5 and runs on a 32bit server. I have migrated it to 4.5.1 working fine now we have got a new server with 64bit and we want to update the application to run on 64bit because we got some OOM exception last days.

When the Build Configuration is set to 64 CPU, I get a System.BadImageFormatException. Under additional information, it says could not load file or assembly dll_name,..... Attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I get this too:

> signtool error no certificates were found that met all the given criteria

but i have a valid certicate to 2018.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you use an external library (due to the `BadImageFormatException` exception), that it isn't platform-independent. One I have experience with is `Oracle.DataAccess`. It comes in two flavors: a 32-bit and 64-bit version of the library.

Make sure you application doesn't use any external libraries that require to run on 32-bits and replace them with their 64-bit counterparts.

Comment: @Moh: need more help?